# What is the difference between "is + xxx-ed" and "will be xxx-ed"?

Tags: present-participles

I am confused about "is xxx-ed" usage,

Sample:

> the system design is translated into programming codes

or

> the system design will be translated into programming codes

Which one is correct?

Plus, any explanation on this "is + past participle" issue would really be helpful.

Comment: Which is correct depends on what you are trying to say. Both are grammatically correct but mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't the faintest idea what those "programming codes" are, and how a system can be "translated" into them. And I worked in IT for over ten years.

Apart from that:

The first example indicates that the "system" (whatever that is) has already been "translated" into "programming codes."

The second example indicates that someone's making a promise that the "system" will be "translated" into said codes at some point in the future.

Now if you lengthened the first sentence a bit, you could indicate that systems of this type are generally translated (like it's a common practice) into "programming codes" (whatever those are). As in:

> When you have a system that needs to be translated into programming codes, the first thing you do is call a conference to discuss things. This happens all the time. Normally, once the conference is over, the system is translated into programming codes. Or not.

Or:

> Buses ***are operated*** by drivers. Sometimes they're operated by wayward skunks or mad robots, but *normally* buses are operated by drivers. (*This* bus ***will be operated*** by a driver at some point in the future).

Comment: @DericJem: You're welcome, chief.